# Pandas, apply simple function to NaN returns value instead of NaN?

Tags: pandas, pandas-apply

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.DataFrame(
  {'a':[0,1,2,3],
   'b':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,3]}
).apply(lambda x: x> 1)
```

returns me `False` for the column b, whereas I would like to get NaN?

```
    a       b
0   False   False
1   False   False
2   True    False
3   True    True
```

Expected

```
    a       b
0   False   NaN
1   False   NaN
2   True    NaN
3   True    True
```

I'd really like my arithmetics to keep track of where I had data and where not, how might I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) or [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) or [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html):

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x> 1).mask(df.isna())
#df = df.apply(lambda x: x> 1).where(df.notna())
```

For better performance avoid `apply`:

```
df = (df > 1).mask(df.isna())
#df = (df > 1).where(df.notna())

print (df)
       a    b
0  False  NaN
1  False  NaN
2   True  NaN
3   True  1.0
```

Last use [nullable boolean](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/boolean.html):

```
df = df.astype('boolean')
print (df)
       a     b
0  False  <NA>
1  False  <NA>
2   True  <NA>
3   True  True
```